# Does IIS cache data that it retrieves from Database?

Tags: caching, iis-6, database-caching

We are using IIS to connect to databases from our App/Web servers. We have one specific call that returns same data over and over from a static table. Is there a way we can cache the data, that is frequently retrieved from databases, in IIS?

We're trying to see if caching can be done at IIS level.